# What does ~run become in Activator?

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I gather that now the 'play' commands are deprecated. I used to be able to start a play app by :

```
>play ~run
```

this would auto-compile on file changes.

So how do I do that in this new weird Activator thing?

(seriously, don't mess with something which works! Not everyone wants to interact using a UI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you type `activator ~run`

Or you can do `alias play=activator` and then type `play ~run`

Activator *adds* two new things, `activator new` and `activator ui`, but if you aren't using those it should be the same as `play` and `sbt`.

The play command is a thin sbt wrapper; activator is a thin sbt wrapper. `~run` is just an sbt command. play/activator should be the same in this respect, except to the extent that Play itself has changed. You can also download sbt and do `sbt ~run`. There should be no difference in behavior between all these ways to run `~run`.

For more background see:

- https://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-activator---an-update-and-roadmap-preview
- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

If `~run` doesn't work as you expect then it most likely isn't an activator-related issue.